# implement a CNN model using Tensorlow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am facing a lot of errors in my project as I am new to this field. Please help me out with these issues. 
Thanks in advance

**Please download the file below and run it in jupyter**
  https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhSiPNeVlPcLhkXPp_9eMWc9b_mC?e=4foE3S

Kind Regards,
Mazhar Bukhari

Comment: Sorry but unless we see the code that produces your errors, then it's impossible to answer

Comment: may be you should post your code and comment what kind of problem you have, eventually some might help you.

Comment: I have posted my code and errors too

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `inception_module` padding to `padding="same"`. This will ensure that the height and width of the output tensor remains the same as the input tensor (32x32).

```
   def inception_module(x,chanDim):
    # x is the input  and chanDim is the dimension at which the convolution is applied
    # channel dimension
    conv_1x1_64 = conv_module(x, 64, 1, 1, (1, 1), chanDim,padding='same') # Convol x with 64 filters of 1X1
    conv_1x1_96 = conv_module(x, 96, 1, 1, (1, 1), chanDim,padding="same") # convol x with 96 filters of 1X1
    conv_1x1_16 = conv_module(x, 16, 1, 1, (1, 1), chanDim,padding="same") # convol x with 16 filters of 1X1 
    conv_3x3 = conv_module(conv_1x1_96, 128, 3, 3, (1, 1), chanDim,padding="same") # convol conv_1x1_96 with 128 3X3 filters
    conv_5x5 = conv_module(conv_1x1_16, 32, 5, 5, (1, 1), chanDim,padding="same") # Convol the conv_1x1_16 with 32 5X5 filters
    maxpool = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(x) # Perform MaxPooling of 3X3, with strides=1
    # padding='same'. Hint:  use MaxPooling2D function 
    conv_1x1_32 = conv_module(maxpool, 32, 1, 1, (1, 1), chanDim,padding="same") # convol maxpool with 32 filters of 1X1
    x = concatenate([conv_1x1_64, conv_3x3, conv_5x5,conv_1x1_32], axis=chanDim)

    return x
```

Comment: still getting same error after changing the padding to same

Comment: After trying it out myself, I see that you're using a stride of 2 (`(2,2)`) for your convolutional layers (`conv_module`) in the inception module. You should change these to stride=1 (i.e. `(1,1)`) to keep the height and width the same.

Furthermore, your MaxPooling layer should also have `padding='same'` in order to keep the correct dimensionality (32x32 on all layers that are concatenated)

Comment: I've modified the original answer to reflect these changes. Hope this should resolve your issues

Comment: I went ahead and fixed the rest of your model. There were some very basic mistakes in the model setup, such as rewriting `x` as a dropout layer without giving it any input, and calling `model.Add...` before even having made the model. Please take a good look at the differences, and feel free to ask any more questions.

Comment: x = inception_module(inputs,chanDim)
    x = downsample_module(x, 80, chanDim)
    x = inception_module(x,chanDim) 
    x = downsample_module(x, 160, chanDim)
    x = Dropout(0.5, noise_shape=None, seed=None)(x)
    
    # softmax classifier
    x= Flatten()(x) # Flatten the x using Flatten() function
    x = Dense(10, input_dim=32)(x) 
    x = Activation("softmax")(x)
    # create the model
    model = Model(inputs, x, name="myNet_function")
    return model